# how to delete user in SSRS using TSQL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have some users in SSRS which I want to delete.
where I try to run:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Users
WHERE dbo.Users.UserName = 'domain\user'
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
  Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
 The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint       
 "FK_Catalog_CreatedByID". The conflict occurred in database "ReportServer",       
 table "dbo.Catalog", column 'CreatedByID'.
 The statement has been terminated.
```

How can I delete users (and all their permissions from SSRS database?

Comment: If you just want to remove permissions you can set the `AuthType` flag in the users table to `0`

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same problem that I wanted to permanently remove users from the SSRS database. So I made this SQL syntax (BACKUP YOUR DB BEFORE!):

```
DECLARE @username varchar(255); SET @username = '<username>';
DECLARE @ownerid uniqueidentifier; SET @ownerid = (SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserName = @username)

BEGIN TRAN

  UPDATE Subscriptions SET ModifiedByID = OwnerID WHERE ModifiedByID = @ownerid
  DELETE FROM Subscriptions WHERE OwnerID = @ownerid
  DELETE FROM Schedule WHERE CreatedById = @ownerid 
  DELETE FROM PolicyUserRole WHERE UserID = @ownerid
  DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserID = @ownerid

COMMIT
```

Replace the `<username>` with the user you want to remove and that's it. But be aware that this also removes other data from this user as well.

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear that you have data in other tables that references the Users table which you are trying to delete.

So  you have two options:

1. Remove the constraints from the Users table and then delete the record and reapply all the constraints again.
2. Remove the data from the referenced tables where your User table is getting referenced.

Answer (score 0):

```
select UserID, u.UserName
into #rs_users
from
    ReportServer.dbo.Users as u 
where userid = 1 -- expression

delete from [ReportServer].[dbo].[PolicyUserRole]
where UserID in (select UserID from #rs_users)

declare @user_name nvarchar(100), @pattern_start nvarchar(300), @pattern_end nvarchar(100), @result nvarchar(max)
declare @start_position int, @end_position int, @sec_data_id uniqueidentifier

DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR
FOR 
select UserName 
from #rs_users

OPEN user_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor INTO @user_name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @pattern_start = '<Policy><GroupUserName>' + @user_name + '</GroupUserName><GroupUserId>'
    set @pattern_end   = '</Policy>'

    DECLARE secdata_cursor CURSOR
    FOR 
        select SecDataID 
        from 
            [ReportServer].[dbo].SecData as sec
        where 
            sec.XmlDescription like '%' + @pattern_start + '%' 

    OPEN secdata_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM secdata_cursor INTO @sec_data_id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        select 
            @start_position = PATINDEX ( '%' + @pattern_start + '%' , XmlDescription ) ,
            @end_position = CHARINDEX(@pattern_end, cast(XmlDescription as nvarchar(max)), @start_position),
            @result = SUBSTRING ( XmlDescription , @start_position , @end_position+len(@pattern_end)-@start_position )  
        from [ReportServer].[dbo].SecData as sec
        where SecDataID=@sec_data_id

        -- replace user to empty
        if @start_position > 0 and @end_position > 0 and len(@result) > 0
        begin
            update [ReportServer].[dbo].SecData
            set XmlDescription = replace(cast(XmlDescription as nvarchar(max)),@result,'')
            where SecDataID=@sec_data_id
        end

        FETCH NEXT FROM secdata_cursor INTO @sec_data_id
    END;

    CLOSE secdata_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE secdata_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor INTO @user_name
END;

CLOSE user_cursor;
DEALLOCATE user_cursor;
```

Comment: Athough this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what the code does and how it helps.